# Probability distribution estimate of target continuous variable

Tags: machine-learning, density-function, continuous-data

I am looking for litterature/reference on algorithms for a regression task that can give the probability distribution estimation of the output variable, or multiple outputs with their respective likelihood. As I am not sure about the correct vocabulary or if this makes any sense, let me illustrate what I am looking for with an example.

Let say I want to predict `age` (continuous). I have 9 binary features, $x_1, .. x_9$ such that when $x_1$ is active, the subject is likely aged `10-19`, $x_2$ for `20-29` and so on until $x_9$ (and more features that allow to have a more detailled estimate).

With algorithms like linear regression that give the most likely output, I fear that in a case where both $x_1$ and $x_6$ are active, the algorithm will average and output `~35` to minimize its loss where I would like it to output that `~17` and `~61` are the most likely answers. In other words, I would like to know if the likelihood of the response given the features is multimodal and get those modes. Or, if simpler, just get the density estimation.

I know I could do this using multi-class classification with `~100` classes, but I expect there exists something built for this purpose.

- What are the algorithms to do this?
- What reference/literature can help with the terminology of this subject?

Answer (score 2):

[Quantile regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_regression) is used to estimate conditional quantiles of the predictions, unlike regular regression which aims at estimating the mean of the distribution. You can then estimate the conditional distribution of the predictions.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is quite old but adding this for future readers.

What comes first in my mind after reading your requirements are [Mixture Density Networks](https://publications.aston.ac.uk/id/eprint/373/1/NCRG_94_004.pdf) (MDNs).

Instead of outputting target estimates, they return the parameters of a probability density function (e.g. mixture of gaussians). These parameters are dependent on the the input, thus accounting for heteroscedasticity (variable output variance) among other things.

In your example, a Mixture Density Network could fit a bimodal probability distribution on your age observations.

Python implementation: [Edward](http://edwardlib.org/tutorials/mixture-density-network)